# Name of Y-like letter symbol LaTeX

Tags: pdftex

I can't find the name of this symbol: [image]

It doesn't seem to be a Greek letter.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Have you tried detexify?

Comment: Where did you encounter it? Could be a J, possibly *Fraktur*, but impossible to tell without more information.

Comment: That looks like a handwritten `J` to me. `\mathcal{J}` could do.

Comment: Is that handwritten?; seems a little degraded in the bottom left corner. Especially if this comes up in discussion of infinite numbers, my guess is that's a Hebrew letter `\beth`, which can be used in mathmode with the `amssymb` package.

Comment: Could also be ℶ₀ (Beth Null). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number

Comment: Try to find it via [detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html)...